# Why is named 'kernel' in machine learning about kernel function?

Tags: machine-learning

can you tell me the origin of `kernel` in machine learning? why is named 'kernel' rather than others? Is there any special meaning? I think the word of `kernel` is very inexplicable or hard to understand.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) states that machine learning borrowed it from the [integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform)

Answer (score 1):

Kernels are classes of algorithms for pattern analysis.  I agree it's a bit of a strange word and I think it's used for historical reasons.

Machine learning can be a bit like that where we'd use "stochastic" when we just mean "random".

Also there's quite a good reply [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-Kernels-in-Machine-Learning-and-SVM) explaining a bit about Kernals in ML.

Hope that helps.